# Extending view in Laravel 5.4 package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am getting `View [layouts.app] not found` **ErrorException** when I extend my app view in another view in a laravel package I am working on.

This is the directory structure I have for the views:

```
vendor
-Student
--myPackage
---src
----views
-----layouts
------app.blade.phph
-----myView
------viewfile.blade.php
```

Now If I extend `layouts.app` like so `@extend('layouts.app')` in `viewfile.blade.php` then I get this **ErrorException** exception. Although, if I don't extend a `layouts.blade` view, I can access the view `viewfile.blade` without any problem.

My views are registered like so in the package `ServiceProvider's boot method

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/Views', 'studentViews');
```

I am using **Laravel 5.4** [Laravel 5.4 Package Development-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#views)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add your package name to the view name as stated in the documentation.

So you would have to use:

```
@extends('studentViews::layouts.app')
```

Comment: Damn. Where is my concentration :( Thanks

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Consider marking this as the solution so other users with the problem might find this solution.